# c++ strings and pointers confusion

Tags: c++, pointers

```
string * sptemp = (string *) 0x000353E0;
```

What does this code exactly want to say ?

I know that in the left side we define a string pointer but I couldn't understand the right part.

Comment: It pretty much screams undefined behavior.

Comment: The right hand side is the *value* given to the object defined on the left. Just like in `int n = 10;`.

Comment: is it same with: string*sptemp;                                                 sptemp=0X000353E0

Comment: somebody need to be fed to the lions of the coliseum.

Comment: Is it written by you or did you find it somewhere else? I don't think it is something you'd see in an actual code

Comment: @CemAytekin: `sptemp=0X000353E0` won't compile. You need a cast (`reinterpret_cast`, or an evil C cast like this one) to allow such a dodgy conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means take a numeric value, convert it to a pointer with that value as the address it points to, and then use that value to initialise the variable `sptemp`.

If the memory at that address contains a valid `string` object, then you can use the pointer to access it. If not, trying to do so will give undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> string * sptemp = (string *) 0x000353E0;
> ```
>
> What does this code exactly want to say ?

It says, treat the data located at address `0x000353E0` as though it holds a `string` and assign the address to the variable `sptemp`. The data can be accessed through the pointer variable `sptemp` after that.

Comment: It actually doesn't say access, does it ? It just says treat it as.

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa, By assigning the value to the variable `sptemp`, you are able to access the value at that address through it.

Answer (score 0):

These comments are mostly right, but not completely.  We don't actually know that string is std::string here.  It could be that string is a bit of memory-mapped hardware whose address on the OP's embedded SBC is defined by the hardware 0x000353E0.  In that case, this is completely sensible, and what people do all the time.  The pointer "string *sptemp" is set to point to the hardware interface.

But it's probably nonsense.